# Xpath expression getting parent element's text

Tags: xslt, xpath, expression

```
<books>
  <physics id="abcd"> Book1 </physics>
  <maths> Book2 </maths>
  <history id="pqrs">Book3 </history>
</books>
```

This xpath expression:

```
select=".//@ID"
```

will give me all the nodes having an id. From there I need to go the parent node and get the text in it.

In the above example, I need to get physics, history as answers. Which xpath expression can give me that result?

Comment: Please format your XML using the `{}` icon

Comment: From you question seems you need the text inside a node. From the comment below you are speaking about getting the element name withint a loop expression that you can't change...You can get a working answer only if you post a meaningful question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=G):

```
//*[@id]/text()
```

The `//*[@id]` will select any element that has an @id attribute.  The `text()` will give you the child text nodes of that element.

---

**Edit:**

To get the name of the node with the `@id` attribute, use the [`name()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256078.aspx) function in XSLT.  [See this example](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=I):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <books>
            <xsl:for-each select="//@id">
                <book><xsl:value-of select="name(..)" /></book>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </books>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.                                               but it still didnt solved the problem. i am inside a loop                         { <xsl:for-each select=".//@ID"> }                                         and from here i need to get the parent's node name.

Comment: I have update my answer with an example of the XSLT solution to getting a node name.

Comment: thanks again. i cant change the looop as it is used by many others, the loop is  <xsl:for-each select=".//@ID"> . from inside this  loop i need to get the name of the element node.

Comment: thanks again. i got the answer name(parent::*) will give the result. thanks once again

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you couldn't change the xpath in your for-each.  You don't need `name(parent::*)`, you can use `name(..)` instead.  I've updated my answer with a new working example.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan the entire document, pick one of these:

```
//*[@id]/text()
//*[@id]/node()
```

With `//*[@id]`, you get all element nodes that have an attribute named `id`.

With `text()`, you only get text nodes; with `node()`, you get all child nodes.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but it still didnt solved the problem. i am inside a loop { <xsl:for-each select=".//@ID"> } and from here i need to get the parent's node name